# angularjs xeditable and angularjs ui-tinymce together in an editable form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is the a way to make a textarea ui-tinymce part of and an editable-form?.
I found a workaround by making ng-model of the editable-textarea and textarea ui-tinymce the same and then I hide the editable-textarea.

```
<form                                   
   onaftersave="onsave({$data:$data})"
   editable-form 
   name="forms.{{formName}}"
   >
   <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions"
      name="desccomp"
      ng-model="item.desccomp"> 
                </textarea>
   <div 
      e-ng-show="false" 
      editable-textarea="item.desccomp"
      e-name="desccomp"
      >
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, TinyMCE already has inline abilities

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/inline/

I'm facing same issue and thinking I'm gonna use only tinyMCE (with angular-ui-tinymce) leaving xeditable for this case).